# fputs() with newline like puts() in C

Tags: c, microbenchmark, puts

In C, `puts(string);` will print `string` to stdout, followed by a newline. `fputs(fileptr, string);`, on the other hand, will write `string` to `fileptr` without the trailing newline. Is there any function like `fputs()` that appends a newline, or should I stick with `fprintf(fileptr, "%s\n", string);` like I've been using?

`fputs()` seems more efficient than `fprintf()` to me as it doesn't parse it's input. I know I could also use

```
fputs(string, fileptr);
fputc('\n', fileptr);
```

but I was wondering if there was a way to do that with one disk write.

I tried to figure out how `puts()` appends the newline (since `printf()` is really just a wrapper for `vfprintf(stdout, ...)`, I thought the same might hold true for `puts()` and `fputs()`), but I oddly cannot find `puts()` in the glibc source.

Comment: *seems more efficient than ...* what profiling have you done that shows a significant difference in the two that is unacceptable and why? Especially since the disk I/O, even with buffering, is orders and orders of magnitude longer than cpu cycles?

Comment: Both those function calls (`fputs(fileptr, string);` and `fputc(fileptr, '\n');`) are wrong.  The file stream parameter comes last, except for `fprintf()` and `fscanf()` and their variants.  The function calls should be `fputs(string, fileptr);` and `fputc('\n', fileptr);`, therefore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I was wondering if there was a way to do that with one disk write.

You're over-optimizing things. The writing to disk *is* buffered, *unless* you happened to mess with the buffering settings or you're using a really bad libc implementation. In general, the best way to achieve what you want is

```
fputs(string, fileptr);
fputc('\n', fileptr);
```

hands down. If you *wouldn't* care about optimization, *or* you believe your compiler would optimize it, you can use

```
fprintf(fileptr, "%s\n", string);
```

it would need to parse the format string - and even then, internally, use the equivalent of `fputs` to write the `%s` and `fputc` to print the newline.

---

However there is one gotcha - be aware that the `FILE` structure usually has some kind of locking for thread safety. `fputs` + `fputc` would require acquiring the lock twice, whereas `fprintf` would probably do it just once. In a single-threaded application the lock wouldn't be contested, however. But it might just be that for a complicated format and multithreaded program, the `fprintf` parsing is faster than acquiring the locks for separate operations. Another is that a call from another thread can interleave the `fputs`/`fputc`, but `fprintf` is supposed to be atomic.

---

P.S. the `puts` code of Glibc is in [`libio/ioputs.c`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/ioputs.c;h=c9967c3883b303979c9a184a1e928345d6dcf3c5;hb=HEAD).

Comment: Is that better than fprintf(fileptr, "%s\n", string);?

Comment: You are way way down in the weeds here @Billy. A good compiler will likely optimize both to be identical. This is implementation defined, but should be close among compilers. The point being made about buffering is that the I/O operations read and write from a `BUFSIZ` buffer (see: C-library source `IO_BUFSIZ` (generally 8192 on Linux and 512 on windoze). So from an I/O standpoint it will be a basic wash. The ideological difference is that `fprintf` is a *variadic* function that generally has additional overhead compared to a function with fixed parameters - but optimization handles most.

Comment: There is the link I was looking for, it's now under [_G_BUFSIZ in Gnu libc (_G_config.h)](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/gnu/_G_config.h) (with `_IO_BUFSIZ` defined as `_G_BUFSIZ` and `BUFSIZ` defined as `_IO_BUFSIZ` in separate header files)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for the writeup. You seem to be write, I ran `strings` on my program after compiling with `fprintf(fileptr, "%s\n", string);`, and I didn't see any occurences of `%s`.

Comment: Easier just to dump to assembly and look at it that way. `gcc -S -O2 -masm=intel -o yourfile.asm yourfile.c` to dump `yourfile.c` to `yourfile.asm` (using intel syntax which I find easier than ATT -- up to you). You will likely find your actual output reduced to a system call to `write`. (you can play with the optimization levels `-O0, -O1, -O2, -O3, -Ofast` and see how optimizations effect the code generation. (and being *way way down in the weed* isn't bad, but you generally end up either profiling, dumping assembly, or at the C-Standard or library source-code to get a final answer)

Comment: If you need to group together operations on a single file stream, a POSIX application can use [`flockfile()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/flockfile.html) and `funlockfile()` and `ftrylockfile()`.  They're designed to be used so that `flockfile(fp); fprintf(fp, "…", …); fprintf(fp, "…", …); funlockfile(fp);` keeps the output from the two `fprintf()` operations consecutive without a chance for another thread to interpose its output.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing will be more effective than :

1. Make sure that your string can accommodate one char more
2. Assign `\n` to the string
3. `fputs` the string